# How to search and replace with regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I have a txt files with some lines containing GPS data, which I need to shorten.

So I have

```
5|{"mResults":0.0|0.0|"mProvider":"fused"|"mDistance":0.0|"mTime":1395061255413|"mAltitude":161.0|"mLongitude":29.0459152|"mLon2":0.0|"mLon1":0.0|"mLatitude":41.0854122|"mLat1":0.0|"mLat2":0.0|"mInitialBearing":0.0|"mHasSpeed":true|"mHasBearing":false|"mHasAltitude":true|"mHasAccuracy":true|"mAccuracy":15.0|"mSpeed":0.425211|"mBearing":0.0}|1395061255413
```

and I need to extract only the coordinates, 
so convert it into this :

```
29.0459152|41.0854122
```

### Edit:

Turns out I need this:

```
GPS|29.0459152|41.0854122|0|1395061255413
```

Please note that I need to :

- add `GPS|` in front, and `|0` at the end.
- and also I need to append the timestamp value (the last value in the original one) `|1395061255413`

How can I do this with Notepad++?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you could do that in **Notepad++**:

1. use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the **Replace** pop-up
2. **tick** `Regular expression` in the `Search mode` section
3. **search** for this pattern: `.*?"mLongitude":(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?"mLatitude":(\d+(?:\.\d+)).*`
4. **replace** the matched string by `\1|\2`
5. click on **Replace all** ;)

---

***How it works:***

The regex pattern featured in my answer **extracts the values** for the longitude and latitude from each line and **replaces the whole line** by:

- the `mLongitude` value,
- a literal "`|`" and
- the `mLatitude` value.

Would you like to have this pattern explained in more details, please check out [this permalink on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wG5dG1).

---

***EDIT:***

To include the *timestamp* you're referring to, you need to use this regex:

```
.*?"mLongitude":(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?"mLatitude":(\d+(?:\.\d+)).*\|(\d+)
```

Then, you just have to change the formatting of your replacement string to this:

```
GPS|\1|\2|0|\3
```

You probably got that already but let's still write down the complete usable solution ;)

I hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome, Thanks! But can you please see my edit to the question? Turns out I also need to extract the last value (timestamp). So I guess we need to add something to the end of this regex. but what ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked ;) Please refer to the edit I just made to my answer to include the revised answer that matches your revised question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks again @ccjmne ! But now it replaces the whole .txt file with a single line containing this : `GPS|29.0|41.085369|0|`

Comment: Oops! I guess that I mistaken. I edited my answer with a less fussy answer that should definitely work as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by this :

search:

```
.*?"mTime":(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?"mLongitude":(\d+(?:\.\d+)).*?"mLatitude":(\d+(?:\.\d+)).*
```

replace :

```
GPS|\2|\3|0|\1
```

But this is because the same data (timestamp) was also inside the string. So this does not extract the timestamp from the end, but from the middle of the string.

So if @ccjmne edits the answer that extracts it from the end, I will accept that answer.

Comment: Hey, that's cool that you found a solution to your problem! I still edited my answer to your question with a regex that extracts the timestamp at the end of each line, as you asked. This time, it should be ok... I tested it ;)